# image zoom feature like imgur.com

Tags: javascript, image, zooming

I  had read somewhere that there is an github repo for js library for the image zoom feature that imgur uses.
you can see one in action here : [imgur sample zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apNnc.jpg)

if you click on banana image you'll notice that you'll see an magnifying glass and on press it zooms it. does anyone know which library it is ?

---

Answer (score 0):

Try [magnifier.js](http://mark-rolich.github.io/Magnifier.js/) it works well for me.